# Batch Scripting to Search text with space in a .log file

Tags: search, text, batch-file, space

I want to search text in a log file.
If found show Error and Text.
Else show Not Found and Text.

```
set str2=Testing Failed in env
findstr "%str2%" SystemOut.log >nul
if not errorlevel 1 ( echo                  ERROR: Testing Failed in env)
if errorlevel 1 ( echo Not Found                             Testing Failed in env!)
```

Whenever in the log file it encounters Testing it says ERROR but it should not do that.
When I try to make changes by adding quotes or something Positive condition gets passed but it fails for negative condition.

Please help me with the script.

Thanks,
Machpatel

Answer (score 1):

You need the /c: switch to include spaces in literal mode.

```
@echo off
set str2=Testing Failed in env
findstr /c:"%str2%" SystemOut.log >nul
if errorlevel 1 ( echo Not Found        "%str2%")
if not errorlevel 1 ( echo found "%str2%")
```